# How can I validate all input fields when a user lands the page and hit the button straightaway?

Tags: angular, formbuilder

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (submit)="submit($event)" [formGroup]="formUser">
    <input name="firstname" formControlName="firstName">
    <input name="lastname" formControlName="lastName">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Is there any way to update any property of formUser, like "touched" or "value", or doing something to validate all the inputs in the submit(ev) function?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can make the input required and disable button if nothing has ever been entered using **ngForm**:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="submit($event)" #myForm="ngForm">
        <input name="firstname" ngControl="firstName" required>
        <input name="lastname" ngControl="lastName" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: my question was different, I don't want to disable the button